# How to kill only current process and continue with shell pipe-line?

Tags: bash, command-line, process-management

I have 2 related Doubts about Bash.

(Q1) Consider `tail -f SomeFile | wc`, a fictitious command-line, where `tail` is used to simulate a command (C1) which runs for a long time, with some output from time to time, and `wc` is used to simulate a command (C2) which processes that output when C1 finishes. After waiting for a long time (longer than usual) I want to see what output has been generated till now, so I want C1 to terminate. But pressing Ctrl-C will kill this whole pipeline. **How can I kill only C1 ( or even a component of C1, if that is itself a compound command ) ?**
If C1 had been looping over many files and grepping some text, but one file was from some hung nfs server, then I want to kill only that grep process.

```
(for F in A B C D E ; do grep sometext $F ; done) | wc
```

Here Ctrl-C will kill the whole command-line, but I want to kill only the currently running (or hung) process and continue with remaining files.

One solution I have, is to open a new connection, get the ps output, and "kill" it. I was wondering if there was a solution from Bash itself, such that some strange key-combination kills only the current process ?

(Q2) While trying to make examples for this question, I made this command-line,Here, where if I press Ctrl-C, I get an extra line of output, like this:

```
# echo `ping 127.0.0.1` | wc
^C

#
```

When backticks (``) are not used, the extra line is not there:

```
# tail -f SomeFile | wc
^C
#
```

Am I correct in thinking that since backticks (``) are handled by bash itself and, when the sub-process is killed, it is still considered as "empty output", so that is printed as the extra line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `bash` you can run:

```
cmd1 | cmd2 | (trap '' INT; cmd3)
```

And a Control-C will only kill `cmd1` and `cmd2`, but not `cmd3`.

Example:

```
$ while sleep .1; do echo -n 1; done | (trap '' INT; tr 1 2)
^C222222222
$ while sleep .1; do echo -n 1; done | tr 1 2
^C
```

This takes advantage of the fact that a signal disposition of "ignore" is inherited by subprocesses -- the `trap '' INT` will also affect the `tr` command. But of course, some commands install their own `SIGINT` handlers, which will break this assumption.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work in `ksh93` because of a stupid bug. A workaround there could be:

```
ksh93$ while sleep .1; do echo -n 1; done | sh -c 'trap "" INT; exec tr 1 2'
^C222222222ksh93$
```

Comment: Nice description of what happens is here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407254/383162 (all commands will receive SIGKILL, but when some program tries to output something to pipe, which is already closed, it will additionaly receive SIGPIPE...)

Answer (score 0):

The command `stty -a` will show you all keyboard shortcuts. The only signals mapped are Ctrl-C (SIGINT), Ctrl-\ (SIGQUIT) and Ctrl-Z (SIGSUSP). There is no binding to other signals.

I would use the solution that you yourself said: separate shell, `ps`output and `kill`the process you need killed.

To your second question, it is not because of the grave accents (``), but because of `echo`. Try this example:

```
# echo `sleep 10` | wc
^C

# `sleep 10` | wc
^C
# sleep `echo "10"` | wc
^C
#
```

Answer (score -1):

Tested with below command   and it worked fine

```
tail -f /var/log/kern.log & read -t 10 ;kill $!
```

Above command will work for only 10 seconds and then get terminated.