# How to pipe a bash command and keep Ctrl+C working?

Tags: bash, pipe

Considering a custom command line software (e.g. loopHelloWorld) which detect ctrl+C for nice shutdown. How to pipe the answer without losing the `Ctrl+C`?

```
$ loopHelloWorld
    - Ctrl+C to nicely shutdown
```

But with pipe, the pipe kill the software without nice shutdown

```
$ loopHelloWorld | 
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        echo "$line"
    done
```

Example

```
ping example.com |
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
  done
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> causes a SIGINT to be sent to all processes in the pipeline (as they're all run in the same process group that correspond to that foreground job of your interactive shell).

So in:

```
loopHelloWorld | 
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
  done
```

Both the process running `loopHelloWorld` and the one running the subshell that runs the `while` loop will get the `SIGINT`.

If `loopHelloWorld` writes the `Ctrl+C to nicely shutdown` message on its stdout, it will also be written to the pipe. If that's *after* the subshell at the other end has already died, then `loopHelloWorld` will *also* receive a SIGPIPE, which you'd need to handle.

Here, you should write that message to stderr as it's not your command's normal output (doesn't apply to the `ping` example though). Then it wouldn't go through the pipe.

Or you could have the subshell running the while loop ignore the SIGINT so it keeps reading the `loopHelloWorld` output after the SIGINT:

```
loopHelloWorld | (
  trap '' INT
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
  done
)
```

that would however cause the exit status of the pipeline to be 0 when you press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.

Another option for that specific example would be to use `zsh` or `ksh93` instead of `bash`. In those shells, the `while` loop would run in the main shell process, so would not be affected by SIGINT.

That wouldn't help for `loopHelloWorld | cat` though where `cat` and `loopHelloWorld` run in the foreground process group.

Comment: To pipe java cli program and use graceful shutdown hooks after CTRL+C, you can start it like this `java -cp myGreatApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar sk.Main | (trap '' INT; tee logfile.txt)` in bash. This solution is described in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213274/how-to-kill-only-current-process-and-continue-with-shell-pipe-line question.

Answer (score 2):

Use a trap:

```
#! /bin/bash

trap handleInt SIGINT

interrupted=0

function handleInt {
    echo "Interrupted..."
    interrupted=1
}


while true
do
    [[ interrupted -ne 0 ]] && { echo "Ctrl-C caught, exiting..." ; exit ; }
    echo "Sleeping..."
    sleep 1
    read -r line
    echo "$line"
done
```

Comment: This seem to capture the `Ctrl+C`, but it does not cancel the sigint neither propagate it to the `loopHelloWorld`

Comment: Improved sample code...